# How to export Roles and dependent selected permissions using Feature module?

Tags: features

I have created some roles and permissiones. I have set dependent permissions to roles. Now, using Feature module, i am able to export and import created Roles and permissions, but not dependent permissions on role accordingly.

Is there any way to do this? or any best module?

Comment: What do you mean by dependent permissions? How are these implemented?

Comment: Suppose i have a role "Manager" and i have 5 custom permissions A, B, C, D, E . Now I have clicked edit permission link and set permissions B, C, D to "Manager" Manager role. Here, Manager have dependent permission B, C, D